# C++ reference to function crashes in a call

Tags: c++, function, templates, reference

I use a templated reference to capture a function by reference-to-function-type but it crashes when I try to call by param() (with Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.38), x86_64-apple-darwin17.2.0)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

int doit(int a, int b) {
    return a+b;
}

template <typename T>
void test(T & param) {
    std::cout << typeid(T).name() << " ";
    std::cout << typeid(param).name() << " ";
    std::cout << param(3,5);
}

int main()
{
    test(doit);
}
```

[image: crash]

But according to Scott Meyers book "Function types can decay into function pointers":

```
void someFunc(int, double); // someFunc is a function; type is void(int, double)

template<typename T>
void f1(T param);       // in f1, param passed by value


template<typename T>
void f2(T& param);      // in f2, param passed by ref

f1(someFunc);       // param deduced as ptr-to-func; type is void (*)(int, double)
f2(someFunc);       // param deduced as ref-to-func; type is void (&)(int, double)
```

So I expect the param to be a reference-to-function-type and call by it.
Whats wrong?

UPDATE: Looks like this is a Clang optimizer bug!
FIX: Evaluation of param's value BEFORE calling by it - fixes the situation!

```
std::cout << param << " - " << (*param)(3,5);
```

Comment: No problem on Linux with Clang 3.8 here.  Your compiler must be producing faulty code.

Comment: Does `typeid` work without including `typeinfo`?

Comment: Android AArch64, GCC 7.2.0, no reproduction.

Comment: @iBug it does, the structure in memory and filled with valid data. The type is FiiiE (function taking int, int ..)

Comment: I am using GCC 4.8.2 and it works. Also in visual studio

Comment: @GorAsatryan weird, so either the Apple CLANG is buggy OR this syntax produces the UB that is unreliable (but still could work on majority of platforms)... hmmm

Comment: @barney Whatever... I include `typeinfo` whenever I use the `typeid` operator.

Comment: This is working properly in cpp.sh.  which compiler are you using

Comment: @Ankur apple clang-900.0.38. Its a bug, I posted the "fix" below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a Clang optimizer bug! 
FIX: Evaluation of param's value BEFORE calling by it - fixes the situation!

```
std::cout << param << " - " << (*param)(3,5);
```